# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, authentication

I am trying to create a login system with windows form c#, but it gives me an error. I am using MySQL database and a tutorial from youtube. I don't know what's the mistake. The project contains three forms: the login one, the register one, and the main program form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace LoginSys
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void registerB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register reg = new Register();
        reg.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void loginB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Teo\Documents\Databases\Login\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        string query = "select * from Table where username = " + username.Text.Trim() + " and password = " + password.Text.Trim() + ");";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
        {
            Register reg = new Register();
            reg.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password","Error");
        }

    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: First go read up in SQL injection, your code is vulnerable. Second, you need to wrap your strings in single quotes. Third, you have a random trailing `)` in your query.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using a connection string made for Microsoft SQL (not MySql) probably won't help either.

Comment: Passwords seem to be stored in plain text, that will be fun later on when you get it working and somebody made a successful sql injection

Comment: If you are getting a SQL exception just the query and the exception text is enough.

Answer (score 2):

`Table` is a really reserved keyword.
Please try this:

```
select * from [Table] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `Table` is a reserved keyword in MySQL/SQL Server, maybe you forgot to rewrite this when copying the code. Make sure that the table where your data is in

```
select * from Table where username = " + username.Text.Trim() + " and password = " + password.Text.Trim() + ");";
```

^ change the Table with the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

the word table is a reserved key word, so the tables name cant be it.
here is a video that explains how to change a tables name https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C7giSRLynY

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34107662)