# SQL Server Syntax Error in variables and Names

Tags: c#

I am making an app with an SQL server login system but I keep getting this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

with Exception unhandled, I am new to programming and I tried to find a solution but none of them have seemed to work...a solution explaining how it works would make it a lot easier.

txtUsername = Name of Textbox,
txtPassword = Name of Textbox for password,
Table is the name of my table in my SQL Server

```
  SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:Documents\DB\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            string query = "Select * from Table Where username = '" +txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and password =  '" +txtPassword.Text.Trim() +"'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("2");
            }
```

Comment: Table is a reserved keyword in SQL. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893220/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-table#42894504

Comment: Having a table named `Table` is a bad idea for several reasons, but it is nevertheless permitted, as long as you escape the keyword using `[]`: `SELECT * FROM [Table]`. Your code contains many other red flags, most notably that you're not using parameters, leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection, and that your passwords are stored in plaintext -- combining these would be a death sentence for a production site, as this would be paradise for a hacker. `SqlDataAdapter` is also getting very long in the tooth. Read up on modern libraries like Dapper, and don't roll your own authentication.

Comment: Also - Please, please, please do not build SQL like this! Please use paramterised queries to prevent SQL injection.